# angularjs video background not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video

am try to make video background use ionic and angularjs i try to put this code in html but the video not working 
`<source class="cvideo" src="background/{{current.currently.icon}}" type="video/webm">`

when run get result

```
<source class="cvideo" src="background/'{{current.currently.icon}}'" type="video/webm">
```

but if i delet path `background` and keep only code `{{current.currently.icon}}` get result name of video

Answer (score 0):

Though you should not have `'` in `href`. Use `ng-src`

```
  <source class="cvideo" ng-src="{{'background/'+ current.currently.icon + '.webm'}}"
   type="video/webm">
```

Comment: but can you pls how use type of video like this `<source class="cvideo" src="background/'{{current.currently.icon}}.webm'" type="video/webm">`